# Eclipse : does it sometimes cause an error even though it has not an issue with code?

Tags: java, eclipse

guys.

I have a question about eclipse program. 
It can be really a dumb question, but I sometimes finds that eclipse makes an error even though the coding has no problem. So I had to restart my computer and then it works again. Is it just my feeling or it actually happens time to time?

I just wanted to know for the future reference.

Thank you!

Comment: whats the error, elaborate your question with details. let other find it easy to understand

Comment: Sometimes that happens when projects aren't "updated". Typically errors go away after rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

That's true, but you don't have to restart!
Go to menu **Project** -> **clean** and then build your project.
However I had this problem log time ago but now I use **Intellij Idea** and it's the best :)

Comment: Oh so that's something that actually could happen!
thank you very much I should try that:)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Try these steps:

1. Go to Project -> Clean (Clean All)
2. Uncheck Build Automatically
3. Click Build All

Your errors should be removed.

Comment: Oh so that's something that actually could happen!
thank you very much I should try that:)